# Scrollto method from ScrollView not working as it should

Tags: android

I have a Linearlayouts, a ScrollView and a button, I am not able to figure out why when I programmatically add a Checkbox to the Linearlayout, at the end of the view, the method from the scrollview

```
scrollview.scrollto(0, ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
```

will not focus the last item added.

here the XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100"
    tools:context="com.eidotab.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="30">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/boton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="TEST"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here the java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ScrollView scrollView;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;
    Button button;

    int num = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                num++;
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                checkBox.setText("TEST " + num);
                checkBox.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                linearLayout.addView(checkBox);

               scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Im also addind the .rar so you just have to download it and try it.. I have spent several hours trying to make it work.. also tried to get the specific child from the LinearLayout with the

```
 y = Linearlayout.getchildat(N).getBottom();
```

and works similar to the FOCUS_DOWN... I can never see the very last item.. only the item before the last.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Here is the program

https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public?preview=MyApplication.rar

Answer (score 0):

Well after some research, seems like there is some kind of problem when trying to perform scrolls programmatically and the solution I have found that work best is to add a runable inside the onClick method in my code so I added

```
scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                }
            });
```

and the end result was

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                num++;
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
                checkBox.setText("TEST " + num);
                checkBox.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                linearLayout.addView(checkBox);

               //scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

                scrollView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        scrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

it is now working flawlessly but that said, I don´t think it is the ideal solution.